# How to force login, after facebook connect?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, mongoid, omniauth

I'm using Rails, Devise, and Omniauth, and I'm trying to login using facebook connect.

But after the facebook part, I'm being redirected to '/users/sign_in#*=*' in my application.

According to the log (see the code), the user is persisted, so this callback is calling the sign_in_and_redirect method:

```
class Users::OmniauthCallbacksController < Devise::OmniauthCallbacksController
  def facebook
    # You need to implement the method below in your model
    @user = User.find_for_facebook_oauth(request.env["omniauth.auth"], current_user)

    if @user.persisted?
      logger.debug "User #{@user.email} is persisted"
      flash[:notice] = I18n.t "devise.omniauth_callbacks.success", :kind => "Facebook"
      sign_in_and_redirect @user, :event => :authentication
    else
      logger.error "User #{@user.email} is not persisted"
      session["devise.facebook_data"] = request.env["omniauth.auth"]
      redirect_to new_user_registration_url
    end
  end
end
```

What could be going wrong?

Note: I'm using MongoID, dunno if that matters. The user is being added correctly to the DB.

**UPDATE**: I have just noticed that Devise is sending me an email to confirm my registration, even when I'm using facebook to authenticate. Maybe this is the problem? How to make the user model :confirmable, except when authenticating with facebook? Is that possible? Here is my User model:

```
class User
  include Mongoid::Document
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :token_authenticatable, :encryptable, :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable,
         :confirmable, :omniauthable

  ## Database authenticatable
  field :email,              :type => String, :null => false, :default => ""
  field :encrypted_password, :type => String, :null => false, :default => ""

  ## Recoverable
  field :reset_password_token,   :type => String
  field :reset_password_sent_at, :type => Time

  ## Rememberable
  field :remember_created_at, :type => Time

  ## Trackable
  field :sign_in_count,      :type => Integer, :default => 0
  field :current_sign_in_at, :type => Time
  field :last_sign_in_at,    :type => Time
  field :current_sign_in_ip, :type => String
  field :last_sign_in_ip,    :type => String

  ## Encryptable
  # field :password_salt, :type => String

  ## Confirmable
  field :confirmation_token,   :type => String
  field :confirmed_at,         :type => Time
  field :confirmation_sent_at, :type => Time
  field :unconfirmed_email,    :type => String # Only if using reconfirmable

  ## Lockable
  # field :failed_attempts, :type => Integer, :default => 0 # Only if lock strategy is :failed_attempts
  # field :unlock_token,    :type => String # Only if unlock strategy is :email or :both
  # field :locked_at,       :type => Time

  ## Token authenticatable
  # field :authentication_token, :type => String

  def self.find_for_facebook_oauth(access_token, signed_in_resource=nil)
    data = access_token.extra.raw_info
    if user = User.where(:email => data.email).first
      user
    else # Create a user with a stub password. 
      User.create!(:email => data.email, :password => Devise.friendly_token[0,20]) 
    end
  end

  def self.new_with_session(params, session)
    super.tap do |user|
      if data = session["devise.facebook_data"] && session["devise.facebook_data"]["extra"]["raw_info"]
        user.email = data["email"]
      end
    end
  end
end
```

I took the code from the devise/omniauth docs: https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/OmniAuth:-Overview

Comment: If you don't override the DeviseController you have the same behavior ?

Comment: I took the code from the devise/omniauth documentation. Without omniauth, devise works fine (I can register, confirm, and be logged in/out), not sure if that's what you are asking

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Had to change the find_for_facebook_oauth method to skip confirmation

```
def self.find_for_facebook_oauth(access_token, signed_in_resource=nil)
  data = access_token.extra.raw_info
  if user = User.where(:email => data.email).first
    user
  else # Create a user with a stub password. 
    user = User.new(:email => data.email, :password => Devise.friendly_token[0,20])
    user.skip_confirmation!
    user.save! 
    user
  end
end
```

Now it works, but it's still adding garbage to the URL. I'm being redirected to '/#*=*', which shows the home page. I'm gonna post another question for this.

Answer (score 1):

To avoid this behavior, you just need define the confirmed_at field when you user is auth by facebook.

In your method `find_for_facebook_oauth` in your model you need add `:confirmed_at => Time.now` in your User creation.